# How to know at runtime the jar in which a resource exists?

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have an images in my jar file and I am using also another jar file that also has images.
How can I know at run time the jar file in which a specific image (resource) exists.

For a class, I can use

```
   getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

But in my case it is an image!

Comment: Why do you (think you) need to know the location?  I've loaded images, HTML, CSS, text files, XML & plenty of other things from Jars on the run-time class-path of the application using `this.getClass().getResource("path/name.type")` to obtain an URL.  If it is an applet or JWS app. that URL will ***always*** point back to the server it came from, even if it is cached locally.  That is done for security reasons.  In short, I've used the URLs to provide to other methods (e.g. `ImageIO.read(URL)`) without ever bothering to inspect or 'know' where it pointed.

Comment: Why does it matter why he wants to do it?

Comment: My application needs to know the jar and based on that an action needs to be taken differently.

Comment: Are you replying to me?  If so, please add @MyName as a prefix so I get notified.  I could tartly respond "What's it to you?"* but instead I'll expand.  People often go about the right feature the wrong way.  If they state the feature, it will sometimes lead to far better ways to do it, which often have nothing to do with what they were originally trying to 'do'.  I could not be bothered typing that explanation ***every*** time it crops up, so just throw it out there as a question.  If the OP has the sense and ability to answer, it could go well for them.  If not, no skin off my nose.

Comment: *"know the jar"*  BTW - the answer to that can be found in my first comment.

Comment: *"an action needs to be taken differently.* " What action? Differently in what way? More details is better than less. **Also** If you could reduce this to a single 'program feature' like 'Offers plug-ins with new terrains & missions' 'Bigger whiter, brighter text'.. what would that *feature* be?

Comment: The answer is getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image path") would return a url that has the jar name. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The URL of a resource has the format `jar:url-of-jar-file!entry-path`. Ignoring error checking:

```
URL resURL = getClassLoader().getResource(resName);
// ==> resURL = jar:ORIGINAL_URL!resName
String path = resURL.getPath();
// ==> path = ORIGINAL_URL!resName
URL jarURL = new URL(path.substring(0, path.indexOf('!'));
// ==> jarURL = ORIGINAL_URL
```

If you can afford creating a connection you can alternatively do this:

```
JarURLConnection conn = (JarURLConnection) resUrl.openConnection();
URL jarURL = conn.getJarFileURL();
```